# Best way to read logged-in user info in Spring boot application when using oAuth to authenticate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth

We are using oAuth to authenticate user in our spring boot application. Our UI (react app) sends a token and using spring security, we validate the token.

Inside our controller, we are doing something like this to get user info:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getResource(@AuthenticationPrincipal jwt){
     jwt.getClaimAsString("username") //This returns user name
}
```

This approach does not seem natural. Is this the best way to get user info? What are other options to get user info in Spring boot application when we use oAuth workflow?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean that it doesn't feel natural?

Comment: @DimitriMestdagh I meant, i have to add `@AuthenticationPrincipal jwt` across all the methods. I would rather have a service which should return this user info when required.

Comment: Normally you can also retrieve the principal by using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`, which you  could wrap in a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Authentication Provider](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider) to convert your OAuth2 Authentication to any object of your choice that implements Authentication. Then you can get that object in any of your controllers with `YourObject user = (YourObject)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`.

Comment: For me security context is null. Not sure if I need to explicitly set it ?

Answer (score 0):

First, use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getClass()` to get the class of the authentication. Then use `TheClass yourAuth = (TheClass) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

Comment: For me security context is null. Not sure if I need to explicitly set it ?